# React Native memory leak when rendering a list of Views

Tags: performance, react-native

[image]

I'm building a recording app and I'm trying to render a waveform. The waveform's data is simply an array of numbers with a max length of 100. I iterate through the waveform array and render 100 `<View />`'s like so:

```
<View style={{ width: screenWidth, position: 'relative' }}>
    {
        this.state.waveforms.map((waveform, i) => {
            return (
                <View
                    key={waveform.key}
                    style={{
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: WAVE_FORM_MAX_HEIGHT - waveform.value + (waveform.value / 2) - WAVE_FORM_MAX_HEIGHT,
                        left: screenWidth - (i * TOTAL_WAVE_FORM_WIDTH),
                        width: WAVE_FORM_MAX_WIDTH,
                        height: waveform.value,
                        backgroundColor: '#CC0000',
                        borderRadius: 2
                    }}
                />
            )
        })
    }
</View>
```

The number of views always stays the same but the RAM continues to increase. Any ideas?

Comment: The number of views don't stay the same. It looks like they increase linearly with the waveforms array. Or do you mean it's of length 100 all the time?

Comment: Oh yeah I should edit that. I meant that the number of views has a capacity

Comment: Hi can you help me to integrate waveform in my task?

Comment: Yeah, what I ended up doing was to use AudioKit (https://audiokit.io/playgrounds/Analysis/Output%20Waveform%20Plot/) and used React Native Bridging